# Jquery .click event not finding item in arraylist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basically trying to have the .attr change the data attribute in the HTML file on a click event, but I'm doing something wrong because I'm receiving an "Error 404 response - file not found" when I click on the button. Thanks for your help.

```
$(function videoShare() {

    var videoID = ['#video1', '#video2', '#video3', '#video4', '#video5', '#video6'],
        thumbnailID = ['#Redwood-video1', '#Redwood-video2', '#Redwood-video3', '#Redwood-video4', '#Redwood-video5', '#Redwood-video6'],
        youtubeID = ["vA3smKNBGUQ", "SEKIre0wH_8", "17SbQ9BlyGM", "O-4pArq9Tnk", "DnVv2ZkiNGo", "N5sPT12O5YU"],
        youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/",
        trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');

    var videoEnlarge = function (el) {
        var videoID = el.data('video-id'),
            thumbnailID = el.data('thumbnail-id'),
            youtubeID = el.data('youtube-url');

        trigger.click(function () {
            var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
                videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video", "youtube-url"),
                videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1";
            $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
            $(".Redwood-videoPopup .close").click(function () {
                $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', "");
            });
            // console.log(youtube);
        });

    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= videoID.length; i++) {
        $(videoID[i]).data('video-id', videoID[i]);
        $(videoID[i]).data('youtube-id', youtube + youtubeID[i]);
        $(videoID[i]).data('URL', URL[i]);

        $(videoID[i]).click(function (e) {
            videoEnlarge($(this));
        });
    }

    videoEnlarge($(videoID[0]));

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="expand" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoEnlarge" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vA3smKNBGUQ" data-ga-event='{"category":"see-whats-new", "action":"video", "label":"expand-video"}'><span>expand<span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you don't assign the value of the `data-video` attribute to your `videoSRC` variable. You are just setting the `data-video` attribute to "youtube-video" and then assigning the return value of the jQuery `attr()` function to `videoSRC`.

Use either

```
videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video");
```

or

```
videoSRC = $(this).data("video");
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Perhaps I wasn't super clear in my issue. So basically, there are 6 videos, each one containing a different videoSRC. I need the videoSRC .attr or .data to change when the user clicks on the "expand" button and that SRC is based on which videoID was clicked prior to clicking the "expand button. Thanks again!

Comment: If this didn't solve your problem: can you create a jsfiddle for a better understanding?

Comment: Good idea! I created a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vjoho310/Lfx7e3pe/1/ As I mentioned before, I need the "expand" button to make the current video selected play in the bootstrap popup. Thanks again!